# Задержка между оправками событий в Qt.

Tags: qt, c++

C++/Qt. Если нажать и удерживать какую-то кнопку на клавиатуре, например `key_left`, то соответствующему виджету высылается событие, потом идёт задержка примерно в секунду, и потом опять начинается высылка событий, пока кнопка нажата. Не подскажете как убрать эту задержку и как настроить задержки между оправками событий при нажатой кнопке?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте изменить ([`keyboardInputInterval`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#keyboardInputInterval-prop)) у глобального экземпляра `QApplication` (например через макрос `qApp`). 
Из документации:

> This property holds the time limit in
> milliseconds that distinguishes a key
> press from two consecutive key
> presses. The default value on X11 is
> 400 milliseconds. On Windows and Mac
> OS, the operating system's value is
> used. This property was introduced in
> Qt 4.2.

Еще можно попробовать использовать `qApp->processEvents()`, чтобы протолкнуть очередь сообщений.

Comment: я попробовал, не это не то. keyboardInputInterval это интервал между двумя последовательными нажатиями(нажать отпустить нажать отпустить). А когда кнопка один раз была нажата и удерживается, тогда идёт высылка событий нажатия и отпускания тоже. мне нужен интервал между этими событиями.

Answer (score 1):

В Qt нет способа из коробки, чтобы изменять интервалы тех системных событий, поступающих от клавиатуры, что Вас интересуют. Вам придётся эмулировать такое поведение вручную. Для начала придётся переопределить защищённые методы нажатия и отпускания клавиши. В них потребуется отслеживать, когда кнопка была нажата, но не была отпущена в течение некоторого минимального интервала времени. Как только данное состояние будет отловлено, начинаете генерировать собственные события (просто создаёте и отправляете соответствующие объекты) нажатия клавиши с нужным кастомным интервалом.

Обратите внимание, что отправку собственных событий необходимо делать через очередь (`QCoreApplication::postEvent()`), поскольку в обратном случае рискуете получить бесконечную рекурсию.

Также потребуется каким-нибудь кастомным флагом различать системные события от собственных, так как последние точно также попадут в соответствующие обработчики событий виджета.